# Shared Toast does not show in Android 3.0.1 on Motorola Xoom

Tags: debugging, android-3.0-honeycomb, toast, android

I use a shared `Toast` across different `Activities` in order to only show the latest message, immediately discarding any previous ones. I put the code in the custom `Application` object:

```
public class GameApp extends Application {
    private Toast mToast;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    public void displayToast(int textId) {
        displayToast(getText(textId));
    }

    public void displayToast(CharSequence text) {
        mToast.cancel();
        mToast.setText(text);
        mToast.show();
    }
}
```

The `Toast` showed up on my `1.6`, `2.2`, and `3.0` emulators. But when I downloaded the released app from the Market, it only shows on my G1 (`CyanMod 6.1`) but not Xoom (`3.0.1`). I tried connecting the Xoom with USB debugging, but nothing relevant showed up in `LogCat`.

Prior to this, I used to do `Toast`s the conventional way (i.e. via `Toast.makeText()`) and that worked on everything as expected.

Could there be any potential problem with my above code, or could this be a bug in the Xoom? Here is the link to [my app](https://market.android.com/details?id=phuc.entertainment.dualnback), in case you want to test it. The `Toast` should show up when you click `Today`, `Progress` in the Main screen. I appreciate any help. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Xoom 3.1. Can anybody confirm this is a bug?

Comment: @vodkhang: Looks like this was due to my misunderstanding of the Toast's API. And my code happened to work on certain versions of Android but not others. Anyway, thanks for starting such a big bounty!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure but the sdk that motorola uses may be different.. and `mToast.cancel()` could be doin something terrible.. so have you tried this..

```
public void displayToast(CharSequence text) {

        mToast.setText(text);
        mToast.show();
    }
```

Comment: yeah since this is open source, people do however they want, terrible. so we should try all possible ways. happy coding...:)

Answer (score 2):

This is because that `mToast.cancel();` may close the toast if it's showing, or **don't show it if it isn't showing yet.**

Please create new Toast object when users click buttons. And keep the previous Toast object reference. Next time when user click buttons, cancel the previous Toast object and create new Toast again.

Comment: Thanks Jett. It turned out I shouldn't have called `cancel()`. I misunderstood the API a bit. `show()` already changes the text instantaneously.

Comment: But if somebody repeat press your "Today" many times, and you do not cancel previous Toast in your activity, you will get many Toast even if you leave the activity.

Comment: Ah sorry for not making myself clear. What I meant was from my code, I only needed to remove the `mToast.cancel()` line. I shared the same instance of Toast between all calls.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GameApp extends Application {
    private Toast mToast;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    public void displayToast(int textId,Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        displayToast(getText(textId));
    }

    public void displayToast(CharSequence text) {
        mToast.cancel();
        mToast = new Toast(mContext);
        mToast.setText(text);
        mToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sherif. Your solution is great too. But it turned out I could simply omit the call to `cancel()` and achieve the desired effect. I wanted to avoid instantiating new Toasts anyway.